# Only select words with all lower case characters javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex to match only words that contain only un-capitalized letters in a string, but cannot figure it out.

Example

```
var str = "What a wonderful Sunday Afternoon";
```

I have managed to match any words beginning with a capital letter using this regex `var str1 = str.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g)`

Here `str1` returns `[What, Sunday, Afternoon]`

What I now want to do is write a regex that returns `a` and `wonderful`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

Just split the string at whitespace, and then filter the array based on whether the word is lowercase.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4s82ovp/)

```js
var string = "What a wonderful Sunday Afternoon";
var lowerCaseWords = string.split(' ').filter(function(word) {
  return word === word.toLowerCase();
});

console.log(lowerCaseWords);
// ["a", "wonderful"]
```

Comment: Unlike `[A-Z][a-z]+`, this solution works with unicode, since `"À".toLowerCase() === "à"`

Answer (score 5):

You could use this regex.

```
\b([a-z]+)\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uQ6lT4/1

Your current regex `[A-Z][a-z]+`

Says one capital letter then any amount of lowercase letters.

Without the `[A-Z]` you're are just looking for all lowercase letters, so partial words are matched. Adding word boundaries will ensure the value is one word (excluding hyphenated words).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below approach

```
var string = "What a wonderful Sunday Afternoon";
string .split(' ').forEach(function(v,k){
if(/[a-z]/.test(v.charAt(0))){
console.log(v);
return v;
}
})
```

```js
    var string = "What a wonderful Sunday Afternoon";
    string .split(' ').forEach(function(v,k){
    if(/[a-z]/.test(v.charAt(0))){
    console.log(v);
    return v;
    }
    })
```